# Where PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH should be set in zsh shell?

Tags: zsh, profile

In my current environment (Fedora35, zsh user shell, oh-my-zsh, pyenv),
`~/.local/bin` is not present in the path.

The question is where is the "right" place to add ?

Several options are available:

- ~/.zshrc
- ~/.zlogin
- ~/.zshenv
- ~/.zprofile

or system wide:

- /etc/zshenv

The role of `/etc/zprofile`, is to source standard `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*sh`, in 'ksh' emulation mode.

```
# from /etc/zprofile

       #  Make /etc/profile happier, and have possible ~/.zshenv options like                      
       # NOMATCH ignored.                                                                          
       #                                                                                           
       emulate -L ksh                                                                              
                                                                                                   
       # source profile                                                                            
       if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then                                                                
           source /etc/profile                                                                     
       fi
```

(see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where)

There are other possibilities (`pam_env`) too.

---

In Fedora, `/etc/profile` contains a block of lines that check for *interactive* shell (with option `i` in `${-}`):

```
                                                                                                   
   for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do                                       
       if [ -r "$i" ]; then                                                                        
           if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then                                                          
               . "$i"                                                                              
           else                                                                                    
               . "$i" >/dev/null                                                                   
           fi                                                                                      
       fi                                                                                          
   done
```

In the test in the line `if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then` the expression `${-#*i}` has no relation with `$i` loop variable but  means: "remove a starting string, ending with `i` (`#*i`) from the list of options `${-}`" and resolves to

```
# with (interactive) zsh

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do echo "<${-#*i}> <$->"; done
<kmsy> <569NRXZghikmsy>
<kmsy> <569NRXZghikmsy>
<kmsy> <569NRXZghikmsy>

# with (interactive) bash

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do echo "<${-#*i}> <$->"; done
<mBHs> <himBHs>
<mBHs> <himBHs>
<mBHs> <himBHs>
<mBHs> <himBHs>
```

---

From: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

> `$-`
>
> Flags passed to script (using set).
> This was originally a ksh construct adopted into Bash ...
> One possible use for it is to have a script
> self-test whether it is interactive.

Probably a way to avoid multiple inclusion of `/etc/profile.d/*sh` in case of *interactive* shell.

This case is handled by `/etc/bashrc` for interactive `bash`.

```
                                                                                                  
# Source global bash config, 
# when interactive but not posix or sh mode                          
   if test "$BASH" &&\                                                                             
      test -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" &&\                                                               
      test "${0#-}" != sh &&\                                                                      
      test -r /etc/bashrc                                                                          
   then                                                                                            
      # Bash login shells run only /etc/profile                                                    
      # Bash non-login shells run only /etc/bashrc                                                 
      # Check for double sourcing is done in /etc/bashrc.                                          
      . /etc/bashrc                                                                                
   fi
```

Comment: Read `man zsh`, the section about "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FIILES`. Be careful, don't add it twice.